# Check if key is below a threshold

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

GIven a key and value and I need the count of 'a'  when it is <50, in the below case count is 2 (30 and 40)

```
import json

# some JSON:
x = '{ "name":"a=30,b=50,a=40,b=44"}'

# parse x:
d = []
c = []
y = json.loads(x).values()
for i in y:
    print((i.replace("=",":")))
   ## Check for threshold value
```

is there a easier way to this?

Comment: This does nothing of that sort.  You do not convert the string of commaseparated assignments to real numbers , so you cannot compare anything of it < 50.

Comment: how to convert ? is my question

Answer (score 1):

You need further preprocessing before you can count `a<50`:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x = '{ "name":"a=30,b=50,a=40,b=44,a=99"}'

# parse x:
d = []
c = []
y = json.loads(x).values()

for i in y:
    # split the string at , to get single assignments
    for assignment in i.split(","):
        inner = {}
        # convert assignmets to key and intvalue 
        a,b = assignment.split("=")
        b = int(b) # this will crash if your input is bad
        inner[a] = int(b)
        d.append(inner)

a_under_50 = [p.get("a",99) < 50 for p in d] # list of True/False

print(d)
# True == 1, False == 0 - if you sum them you get your output
print(sum(a_under_50))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 30}, {'b': 50}, {'a': 40}, {'b': 44}, {'a': 99}]

2
```